# how to put value in the checkboxes

Tags: java, swing, checkbox

this is my code, I just want to make a receipt that when you check the checkbox theres value in it and it prints the label with the value consecutively

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener

{

private JLabel label;
private JCheckBox checkbox,checkbox2,checkbox3,checkbox4,checkbox5,
checkbox6,checkbox7,checkbox8,checkbox9,
checkbox10,checkbox11,checkbox12,checkbox13,checkbox14,checkbox15,
checkbox16,checkbox17,checkbox18,checkbox19,checkbox20;
 private JButton button;


public GUI()
{
Container pane= getContentPane();
pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(15,1));

JPanel jp= new JPanel();

label= new JLabel("McDonald's");
checkbox = new JCheckBox("Cheese Burger");
checkbox2 = new JCheckBox("Big Mac");
checkbox3 = new JCheckBox("Big n' Tasty");
checkbox4 = new JCheckBox("McSpicy");
checkbox5 = new JCheckBox("Quarter Pounder with Cheese");
checkbox6 = new JCheckBox("Double Cheeseburger");
checkbox7 = new JCheckBox("McChicken Sandwich");
checkbox8 = new JCheckBox("Filet-O-Fish");
checkbox9 = new JCheckBox("Cheeseburger Deluxe");
checkbox10 = new JCheckBox("Burger Mcdo");
checkbox11 = new JCheckBox("Chicken Filet with Drinks");
checkbox12 = new JCheckBox("Spaghetti with Drinks");
checkbox13 = new JCheckBox("Hot Fudge Sundae ");
checkbox14 = new JCheckBox("Caramel Sundae");
 checkbox15 = new JCheckBox("Large Mcdo French Fries");
checkbox16 = new JCheckBox("Chicken Nuggets with coke");
checkbox17 = new JCheckBox("Coke Float");
checkbox18 = new JCheckBox("Green Apple Float");
checkbox19 = new JCheckBox("Crispy Chicken with rice");
checkbox20 = new JCheckBox("Oreo Sundae");
button = new JButton("Order Now");

add(label);

pane.add(checkbox);
pane.add(checkbox2);
pane.add(checkbox3);
pane.add(checkbox4);
pane.add(checkbox5);
pane.add(checkbox6);
pane.add(checkbox7);
pane.add(checkbox8);
pane.add(checkbox9);
pane.add(checkbox10);
pane.add(checkbox11);
pane.add(checkbox12);
pane.add(checkbox13);
pane.add(checkbox14);
pane.add(checkbox15);
pane.add(checkbox16);
pane.add(checkbox17);
pane.add(checkbox18);
pane.add(checkbox19);
pane.add(checkbox20);

add(button);
add(jp, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

button.setSize(10,10);
button.addActionListener(this);

setSize(500,550);
setVisible(true);

 }
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
 {
 String gulp = e.getActionCommand();
{
if ( gulp.equals("Order Now"))
   {
   new Receipt();
  setVisible(true);
  dispose();
}
}
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
GUI r= new GUI();
}
}
```

here is my second code, this is the format of the receipt I want to achieve

```
    import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Receipt extends JFrame
{

private JLabel label,label2,label3,label4,label5,
label6,label7,label8,label9,label10;;


public Receipt()
{
    Container pane= getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(13,1));

    label= new JLabel("MC DONALD'S");
    label2= new JLabel("McDonald's Tandang Sora");
    label3= new JLabel("#22 Tandang Sora Corner, Commonwealth Avenue, Quezon City");
    label4= new JLabel("Telephone# (02)86236");
    label5= new JLabel("MACHINE SERIAL NUMBER: D123HJ01");


    label6= new JLabel("Card Issuer: Sharina Tortoles");
    label7= new JLabel("Account Number# 337163990");
    label8= new JLabel("February 22, 2014  12:45");
    label9= new JLabel("Thank You for choosing Mcdonald's");
    label10= new JLabel("Please come again");


    label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label2.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label3.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label4.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label5.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label6.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label7.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label8.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label9.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label10.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

    pane.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    pane.add(label2);
    pane.add(label3);
    pane.add(label4);
    pane.add(label5);
    pane.add(label6);
    pane.add(label7);
    pane.add(label8);
    pane.add(label9);
    pane.add(label10);


    setSize(500,500);
    setVisible(true);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    Receipt g= new Receipt();

  }
 }
```

Hope that it is clear to you what I want to happen with code

Comment: _"Hope that it is clear to you what I want to happen with code"_ - It's really not. And you haven't really asked a question. What's not working?

Comment: My crystal ball says: For each checkbox that is selected in the `GUI` you want to add a `JLabel` to the `Receipt` frame. This label should contain the same string as the string for the respective check box that was selected. Is this correct?

Comment: yes it is. And I also want the value of the checkbox seen at the receipt frame as well as the label that is the same string as the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `EnumSet` is what you are looking for:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

enum Receipt {
  CheeseBurger("Cheese Burger"),
  BigMac("Big Mac"),
  BigNTasty("Big n' Tasty"),
  McSpicy("McSpicy"),
  QuarterPounderWithCheese("Quarter Pounder with Cheese"),
  DoubleCheeseburger("Double Cheeseburger"),
  McChickenSandwich("McChicken Sandwich");
  //JCheckBox("Filet-O-Fish"),
  //JCheckBox("Cheeseburger Deluxe"),
  //JCheckBox("Burger Mcdo"),
  //JCheckBox("Chicken Filet with Drinks"),
  //JCheckBox("Spaghetti with Drinks"),
  //JCheckBox("Hot Fudge Sundae "),
  //JCheckBox("Caramel Sundae"),
  //JCheckBox("Large Mcdo French Fries"),
  //JCheckBox("Chicken Nuggets with coke"),
  //JCheckBox("Coke Float"),
  //JCheckBox("Green Apple Float"),
  //JCheckBox("Crispy Chicken with rice"),
  //JCheckBox("Oreo Sundae");
  private final String str;
  private Receipt(String str) {
    this.str = str;
  }
  @Override public String toString() {
    return str;
  }
}

public class GUI2 {
  private JButton button = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Order Now") {
    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      EnumSet<Receipt> r = EnumSet.noneOf(Receipt.class);
      for (ReceiptCheckBox c: list) {
        if (c.isSelected()) {
          r.add(c.getReceipt());
        }
      }
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((JComponent) e.getSource(), r);
    }

  });
  private List<ReceiptCheckBox> list = new ArrayList<>(Receipt.values().length);

  public JComponent makeUI() {
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    for (Receipt r: Receipt.values()) {
      ReceiptCheckBox c = new ReceiptCheckBox(r);
      list.add(c);
      p.add(c);
    }
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(new JLabel("McDonald's"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    panel.add(p);
    return panel;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new GUI2().makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class ReceiptCheckBox extends JCheckBox {
  private final Receipt receipt;
  public ReceiptCheckBox(Receipt receipt) {
    super(receipt.toString());
    this.receipt = receipt;
  }
  public Receipt getReceipt() {
    return receipt;
  }
}
```